# Open URI Wrong Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, open-uri, cloudinary

I am trying to download images from the web and upload them back to Cloudinary. The code I have works for some images, but not for others. I have isolated the problem down to this line (it requires `open-uri`):

```
image = open(params[:product_image][:main])
```

For [this image](http://www.spiresources.net/WebImages/480/swatch/BLKW.JPG), it works fine. `image` is

```
#<Tempfile:/var/folders/49/bmhbmmzj5fl31dm9j6m6gxr00000gn/T/open-uri20150526-7662-1b676ws>
```

and cloudinary accepts this. However, when I try to pull [this image](http://www.spiresources.net/WebImages/480/swatch/CELW.JPG), image becomes

```
#<StringIO:0x007fa0267c8f80 @base_uri=#<URI::HTTP:0x007fa0267c92c8 URL:http://www.spiresources.net/WebImages/480/swatch/CELW.JPG>, 
@meta={"date"=>"Tue, 26 May 2015 22:17:47 GMT", "server"=>"Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)", 
"last-modified"=>"Mon, 29 Jun 2009 00:00:00 GMT", "etag"=>"\"44700f-c35-46d715f090000\"", 
"accept-ranges"=>"bytes", "content-length"=>"3125", "content-type"=>"image/jpeg"}, @metas={"date"=>["Tue, 26 May 2015 22:17:47 GMT"], "server"=>["Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)"], 
"last-modified"=>["Mon, 29 Jun 2009 00:00:00 GMT"], "etag"=>["\"44700f-c35-46d715f090000\""], "accept-ranges"=>["bytes"], 
"content-length"=>["3125"], "content-type"=>["image/jpeg"]}, @status=["200", "OK"]>
```

which cloudinary rejects and raises an error of "No conversion of StringIO to string". Why does `open-uri` return different objects for what would seem like similar images? How can I make `open-uri` return a `tempfile` or at least turn my `StringIO` to a `tempfile`?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply give the URL to the Cloudinary upload method. Then Cloudinary will fetch the remote resource directly.